# Simrank implementation

Tags: python, graph, data-science

I was trying to implement [Simrank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimRank) from scratch without using networkx. I am new to graphs and graph theory and I couldn't totally understand how to actually calculate the In-neighbours of a node in the graph. Can anyone please help me with the concept and how to calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

To get in-neighbours of a given node, you first have to decide how do you store a graph. Most famous ways to store a graph are a matrix and a dictionary.

Suppose you have a graph (A)->(B)->(C). In this case, in-neighbour of node (B) is (A).

How do you store this graph and get information about neighbours?

As a dictionary:

```
graph = {'A': ['B'],
         'B': ['C']}

for k, values in graph.items():
        if 'B' in v:
            print(k)
```

As a matrix:

```
graph = [[0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0]]
```

Here's how you read this matrix. 0 means there is no edge, 1 means there is an edge. If you look at the first row, you'll see 1 in the middle. This means there is an edge from A (because it's a first row) to B (because "1" is in the second column). Conversely, if you look at upper-left 0, it means there is no edge from A to A. Or look at upper-right 0, it means there is no edge from A to C.

So to get all nodes that are connected by an edge with B, you have to select 1's from the second column.

Note: examples above describe *directed* graphs. There are also *undirected* graphs. In undirected case your matrix will be symmetric, and your dictionary will contain not only (A)->(B) but (B)->(A) as well.

Answer (score 0):

In neighbours exist only for directed graphs.A in-neighbour is a node which is pointing TO a node then the first node is the in-neighbour of the second.
The second node is the out-neighbour of the first node.
Hope this helps.